# Writing dataframe to SQL Server with df.write.jdbc() produces error: Column has a data type that cannot participate in a columnstore index

Tags: sql-server, apache-spark, pyspark

I'm using pyspark with spark 2.2 and python 2.7 in a cluster of 20 nodes. I'm loading data into a dataframe from cloud blob storage using `df = spark.read.jdbc(...)` and then I attempt to write it into my SQL Server database with `df.write.jdbc(...)`. However, during the write process I get the following error:

`py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o67.jdbc.
: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The statement failed. Column 'my_col' has a data type that cannot participate in a columnstore index.`

The `df`'s schema is as follows:

`root
 |-- my_col: string (nullable = true)
 |-- my_other_col: string (nullable = true)
 ...`

[This post](https://raresql.com/tag/create-index-statement-failed-column-has-a-data-type-that-cannot-participate-in-a-columnstore-index-omit-column/) has me believing that `df.write.jdbc(...)`maybe trying to create columnstore indexes for all columns in the df when it writes. Unfortunately I do not know how to stop spark from doing this so I can mitigate this issue.

A summarized version of my code looks like this:

```
spark = (pyspark.sql.SparkSession.builder
             .appName('my-app').getOrCreate())

df = (self.spark.read.format('com.databricks.spark.avro')
                      .options(inferSchema=True, header=True)
                      .load(blob_storage_path)).repartition(self.num_partitions)

df.write.jdbc(url=self.jdbc_url, table=table, mode='overwrite',
                          properties=self.jdbc_properties)
```

Here's the full stack trace:

```
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o68.jdbc. 
:  com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The statement failed. Column 'my_col' has a data type that cannot participate in a columnstore index.
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException.makeFromDatabaseError(SQLServerException.java:217)
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.getNextResult(SQLServerStatement.java:1655)
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.doExecuteStatement(SQLServerStatement.java:885)
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement$StmtExecCmd.doExecute(SQLServerStatement.java:778)
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSCommand.execute(IOBuffer.java:7505)
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.executeCommand(SQLServerConnection.java:2445)
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.executeCommand(SQLServerStatement.java:191)
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.executeStatement(SQLServerStatement.java:166)
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.executeUpdate(SQLServerStatement.java:703)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JdbcUtils$.createTable(JdbcUtils.scala:805)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JdbcRelationProvider.createRelation(JdbcRelationProvider.scala:90)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource.write(DataSource.scala:472)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.SaveIntoDataSourceCommand.run(SaveIntoDataSourceCommand.scala:48)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.ExecutedCommandExec.sideEffectResult$lzycompute(commands.scala:58)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.ExecutedCommandExec.sideEffectResult(commands.scala:56)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.ExecutedCommandExec.doExecute(commands.scala:74)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:117)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:117)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$executeQuery$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:138)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeQuery(SparkPlan.scala:135)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.execute(SparkPlan.scala:116)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.toRdd$lzycompute(QueryExecution.scala:92)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.toRdd(QueryExecution.scala:92)
at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.runCommand(DataFrameWriter.scala:610)
at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.save(DataFrameWriter.scala:233)
at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.jdbc(DataFrameWriter.scala:461)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:280)
at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:214)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Thanks in advance for any help you can provide!

Answer (score 0):

What SQL Server version do you have? There are some restrictions to the datatypes that could be in columnstore index in versions earlier than 2017. Read restrictions section of this article https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-columnstore-index-transact-sql The thing you can do, I guess, is drop the columnstore index or to migrate to Sql Server 2017.

Comment: I'm on SQL Server 2008 SP3, the exact version number is 10.0.9397.48. Unfortunately migrating to SQL Server 2017 isn't an option. While I do not want to drop any columns of the data I am attempting to upload to the DB I would be fine with not creating any column store indexes. I believe the issue here is that I cannot find out how to change the `df.write.jdbc(...)` call from making columnstore indexes.